# memset to INT_MAX in C++

Tags: c++, c, memset

I have the following code:

```
int board[5][5];

memset(board, INT_MAX, sizeof(board));
//printing out INT_MAX
cout << INT_MAX << endl;

for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
            cout << setw(3) << board[r][c];
        }   
        cout << endl;
}
```

For some reason i am getting all `-1`s in my array:

```
2147483647
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

How can I explain? Why aren't all the elements setting to INT_MAX?
When I print `INT_MAX` it is printed out fine.

Comment: `memset(board, XXX, sizeof(board));` set the value `XXX` for each byte of `board[][]`  (maybe 100 bytes).  No reasons to think setting each byte (8-bits) will result in each `int` having the value of  `INT_MAX`.

Comment: but `man memset` shows the function signature as `void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);` So why isn't the second argument int?

Comment: @kmad1729 the second argument is `int`, but that value is converted to a byte (`unsigned char` specifically) and the result of that conversion is applied to every byte in the array

Comment: Reading the documentation (always a good idea when code does not work as expected): `void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);` "The memset function copies the value of c (converted to an **unsigned char**) into each of the first n characters of the object pointed to by s."

Comment: Is this C++?  If so, then you could have used `std::fill`: `std::fill(&board[0][0], &board[5][5], INT_MAX);`  [See this](http://ideone.com/whq7j1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter to `memset()` is a single byte. `memset()` does not fill the specified area of memory with `int`s, but with single bytes.

If you want to initialize your `board` array of `int`s, you'll have to do it with the same kind of a loop that your test program uses to print its contents.

Comment: e.g. in C++ std::fill.